# Read socket is blocked

Tags: tcl

I'm writing a socket utility to communicate a client to a server.  When input to the socket from the client side, the server is receiving it fine.  However, when input to the socket from the server, the client can't read.  When checking for fblocked $channel.  It is 1.  I've tried everything including adding new line, ...
Please help.

Below is my code

```
proc read_command { sock } {
  variable self
  global connected

  set len [gets $sock line]
  set bl  [fblocked $sock]
  puts "Characters Read: $len Fblocked: $bl"

  if {$len < 0} {
     if {$bl} {
        puts "Input is blocked"
     } else {
        set connected 1
        puts "The socket was closed - closing my end"
        close $sock
     }
  } else {
     if {!$bl} {
        puts "Read $len characters: $line"
        catch {uplevel #0 $line} output
        puts "1==>$output<=="
        puts $sock "$output"
        puts $sock "\n"
        flush $sock
     }
  }
}

proc client { host port } {
  variable self
  set s [socket $host $port]
  set self(csock) $s
  set self($s,addr) $host
  set self($s,port) $port
  fconfigure $s -buffering line -blocking 0
  return $s
}

proc prun { sock args} {
  variable self
  set result [list]

  set cmd $args
  set cmd [regsub -all {(^\s*\{)||(\}\s*$)} $cmd ""]
  set cmd [string trimleft $cmd]
  set o1 [eval $cmd]
  #catch {uplevel #0 $cmd} o1

  puts "1_$sock ==> $o1"

  lappend result $o1
  #--------------
  puts $sock $cmd
  flush $sock

  set bl [fblocked $sock]

  set file [read $sock]
  set bl [fblocked $sock]
  puts "Fblocked: $bl"
  puts "Output: $file"

  puts "2_$Comm::self(csock) ==> $file ==> $bl"

  lappend result $file
  return $result
}
```

Here is how I run it.

1. I call server on 1 of the terminal.  It will echo the ip address and the port.
2. Then I call client using the address and the port above to get back the client socket
3. Then I call prun on the client shell to get back a pair of values, one with the value of the cmd call on the client, and the other the value of the cmd call on the server.  Basically I would like to get the pair of values so I can use them for correlation between the 2 set of data.

Below is the code:
1.
On server shell

```
$ server
```

2.
On client shell

```
$ set s [client $addr $port]
```

3.
Call a proc to get the value from the client shell, then send the command to the server to get the value from the server shell, and return that value back to the client.

```
$ set res [prun $s {set val [get_attribute [get_nets mynet] pin_capacitance_max]}]
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention that.  The same line of code "set file [read $sock]" works just fine on the shell command line.  However, it never works inside the proc

Comment: I've tried to debug by testing "fblocked $sock" and it is all 0 before getting to the mentioned "set file [read $sock]".  After that it turns 0.  I don't know what cause that line of code to turn the socket into blocking.

Comment: You've given us some procedures, but not the code that calls them. How do the bits fit together?

Comment: Hi Donal Fellows, the code to run is below

Comment: Hi, I've been able to get what I want in the book "Practical Programming in Tcl and Tk" page 653.  Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
puts "2_$Comm::self(csock) ==> $file ==> $bl"
```

and defined *self* with **variable**. Are you working with packages?. May be you forgot something related to it.

For test you can use just **global** but using arrays would be a little more complicated.

Comment: Hi Alejandro,  I tried that too.   It's not working.  I've been trying all the possible things I can think of and it still doesn't work.  I think I have done something wrong fundamentally.  Just don't know what that is

Comment: Are you looked this : [wiki:socket](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1114) or
[wiki:the simplest example](http://wiki.tcl.tk/15315) ?

Comment: Hi Alejandro, like I've mentioned.  The command "read $sock" works on the shell, but it doesn't work when I put it in the proc.